# How to Set null Into QueryDSL Timestamp Column During Update?

Tags: java, spring-data, querydsl

I have the following table in Postgre:

```
CREATE TABLE user_attempts
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    attempts SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    lastmodified TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY ( username ) REFERENCES users ( username )
);
```

I would like to update the `lastmodified` field through QueryDSL and Spring Data JDBC Extension as follow:

```
template.update(userAttempts, update -> update
                .set(userAttempts.attempts, (short) 0)
                .set(userAttempts.lastmodified, null) // compilation error here
                .where(userAttempts.username.eq(username))
                .execute();
```

However, it seems that QueryDSL's set method can't accept `null` because it will match more than one function signatures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on this QueryDSL issue: https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/846

I should use `setNull` method instead:

```
template.update(userAttempts, update -> update
                .set(userAttempts.attempts, (short) 0)
                .setNull(userAttempts.lastmodified)
                .where(userAttempts.username.eq(username))
                .execute()
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably have to cast `null` to the type of `lastmodified`. E.g.:

```
.set(userAttempts.lastmodified, (Timestamp) null)
```

The reason for this is that the `null` literal is ambiguous when calling overloaded generic methods.